# order a result set in unnatural order

Tags: mysql, sql

I understand the normal `ASC` and `DESC` `ORDER BY` clause.

However, I have a case where table contains a column `unitType` where `unitType` can be 0, 1 or 2. I need to sort my result set so that the rows returned are in a particular order depending the value of the `unitType` column.

This is the closest I have gotten:

```
SELECT * FROM `units` WHERE `unitType`=0
union 
select * from units where unitType=2
union 
select * from units where unitType=1
```

This lists my rows with `unitType=0`, followed by those with value 2 and finally 1. Is there a better way to do this? I need to alter this query to fetch rows in any particular order e.g. 2, 0, 1 etc.

Comment: Thank you everyone, i wish i could mark more than one answer as accepted. I chose the one with the simplest syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * from units
order by
  case when unitType = 0 then 1
       when unitType = 1 then 3
       else 2 end
```

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT *
    FROM units
    WHERE unitType IN (0,1,2)
    ORDER BY CASE WHEN unitType = 0 THEN 1
                  WHEN unitType = 2 THEN 2
                  WHEN unitType = 1 THEN 3
             END
```

Comment: or `CASE unitType WHEN 0 THEN 1 WHEN 2 THEN 2 WHEN 1 THEN 3 END`

Comment: @Benoit: To-may-to, to-mah-to. :-)

Comment: @Steanelli: no native English speaker. What do you mean?

Comment: @Benoit: It's two different pronunciations of the word tomato. It's an expression in English used to convey the idea that we've chosen two different, but equally valid, ways of expressing the same idea.

Comment: Steanelli: thanks for the explanation. Should be migrated to english.SE :)

Comment: ihihihih http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55062/what-does-it-mean-to-may-to-to-mah-to/55063#55063

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the **[`FIELD()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_field)** function:

```
SELECT * 
FROM units 
ORDER BY FIELD(unitType, 0,2,1)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd create a seperate SortOrder table (UnitType,Ordinal) and use that to define ordering. You'd then use UnitType to join to that table and order results by Ordinal.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than 'hiding' this logic in the `ORDER BY` clause of a query, consider creating a table to map unitType and sort order values (e.g. a two-column base table), join to this table in queries and include the sort order attribute in the `SELECT` clause **and** the `ORDER BY` clause (to expose the sort order to the calling application).